# Printing very big numbers

Tags: haskell

I begin to learn Haskell and I don't understand what happens : I have a very simple code :

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

fact n = product [1..n]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    input_line <- getLine
    let m = read input_line :: Int
    print (fact m)
    return ()
```

In ghci, when I try

```
*Main> :load "fact.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( fact.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> main
4500
0
```

but

```
*Main> fact 4500
2274299510944531831673.....
```

What am I missing ?
Thank you for any explanation.

Comment: `Int` is a bounded size type.  Ghci is defaulting to unbound `Interger`s.

Comment: Some style advice: **1.** `return ()` is usually unnecessary **2.** most Haskellers have a slight preference for `print $ fact m` over `print (fact m)` **3.** you should always write type signatures for your top-level definitions.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for these advices

Comment: Another style advice in addition to leftaroundabout's comment: maybe `m <- readLn :: IO Int` would be better in your situation, rather than `input_line <- getLine; let m = read input_line :: Int`. I personaly would have written `main = print . fact =<< (readLn :: IO Integer)`.

Comment: @baxbaxwalanuksiwe : you have a level in Haskell that I don't have, I was sure that there exists a better to way to write the first 2 lines of main but I didn't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `fact` is `Num a => a -> a`. In your `main`, you're applying it to `m`, which you declared to be an `Int`. So the result of `fact` will be an `Int` and all calculations in between will be done using `Int`s. `Int`s are fixed-width integers and can't represent numbers that big, causing an overflow and thus wrong results.

On your second try, you're applying `fact` to `4500` without specifying which type you want `4500` to be. In cases like that, Haskell uses the default number type, which is `Integer`. Unlike `Int`, `Integer` can represent integers of any size, so the code just works.

If you did `fact 4500 :: Int`, you'd get the same wrong result as the first time. Similarly if you use `:: Integer` in your `main` instead of `Int` (or leave it off, so the default is used again¹), you'll get the correct result.

---

¹ Do note that this would produce a warning though. Explicitly annotating the type instead of relying on defaulting rules is usually preferable outside of GHCi or small test programs.

Comment: If you left out any type annotation in `main`, you'd get `Integer` by the same defaulting rules.

Comment: @Alec Right, I've added that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I begin to understand the integers in Haskell. I tried Int64 with the same result. I thought Int64 would be enough big...

Comment: @joel76 The biggest positive int64 has 63 digits in base 2, which are all 1, plus the sign bit. 450! has 14488 digits in base 10 - more than that in base 2. So even a 128 bit number wouldn't come close to being able to represent 450!.

Comment: @joel76 the factorial grows just stupendously fast, which is one reason why it's almost never actually used in practice. In most application where one might be tempted to use factorials, you really want the binomial-coefficient function (which can be implemented with factorials, but much more efficiently without). In other applications, it makes sense to apply the Stirling approximation (in floating-point).